# cubic spline interpolation - spline interval

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, spline

The k function values are to be interpolated by a piecewise cubic spline. The k-1 cubic polynomials are defined on the intervals [xi,xi+1],i ∈ {1,...,k-1}. Indicate which of the following statements apply in general.

1. For each spline interval, a system of equations is set up, solved and thus the polynomial for the interval is determined.
2. The system matrix for calculating the cubic spline is singular if xi=xj, i≠j.

I think the first statement is not true and the second is, but I would like to be sure.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It is impossible to answer because you don't say whether or not the spline functions are "clamped" at both ends.